# Apache fails to start with - "bad user name" in stdout.log. I specified LDAP user in httpd.conf.

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.01 and Apache - 2.2.31.
In httpd.conf I have

```
User build
Group build
```

Trying to start apache -

```
apache/logs$ cat stdout.log
httpd: bad user name build
```

Before that I tried to run:

```
. bin/envvars
```

When I created local user "test"

```
useradd -m test -G sudo -s /bin/bash
```

and specified it in httpd.conf, then I was able to start apache. 
But, I need to use LDAP user "build".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this issue:

```
sudo ltrace -f sh apachectl configtest 2>out.log
```

Investigated output in out.log file and found a call - `'getpwnam("build")'`, which returned '0'. From [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam) I understood that "The given name or uid was not found.", but when I was calling 'id build' I was able to see that user exist and list of the network groups to which this user belongs to. Then I connected to another vm, where I was able to use LDAP user to start apache and ran

```
ldd bin/httpd
```

and compared the output. One of vm's was missing "libldap-2.3.so.0"